# xcodebuild failed with code 65

Tags: selenium, appium, xcode8

When i try to launch App with Appium getting below error

```
[debug] [XCUITest] Error : Command 'bash -c "ps -ax|grep -i \"xcodebuild\"|grep -i \"faea4372d3a65bdb23969752f0d5902ca21c5571\"|grep -v grep|awk '{print \"kill -9 \" \$1}'|sh"' errored out: Error: spawn bash ENOENT
```

I've tried by adding Code_signing and team id with xcodeconfig capability but it is not working, could you please help me on this
Below are the capabilities set to

```
 app: '/Users/arun/Documents/App/iOSAutomationTests/src/main/resources/test.ipa'
rotatable: true
newCommandTimeout: 120
realDeviceLogger: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deviceconsole'
platformVersion: '10.1.1'
automationName: 'XCUITest'
xcodeConfigFile: '/src/main/resources/myconfig.xcconfig'
platformName: 'iOS'
udid: 'faea4372d3a65bdb23969752f0d5902ca21c5571'
deviceName: 'faea4372d3a65bdb23969752f0d5902ca21c5571'
autoAcceptAlerts: true
```

Below is the log

```
XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: /usr/local/bin/carthage
[debug] [XCUITest] Killing hanging processes
[debug] [XCUITest] Error : Command 'bash -c "ps -ax|grep -i \"xcodebuild\"|grep -i \"faea4372d3a65bdbd7969752f0d5948ca21c5571\"|grep -v grep|awk '{print \"kill -9 \" \$1}'|sh"' errored out: Error: spawn bash ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[debug] [XCUITest] Error : Command 'bash -c "ps -ax|grep -i \"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deviceconsole\"|grep -i \"faea4372d3a65bdbd7969752f0d5948ca21c5571\"|grep -v grep|awk '{print \"kill -9 \" \$1}'|sh"' errored out: Error: spawn bash ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[debug] [XCUITest] Error : Command 'bash -c "ps -ax|grep -i \"iproxy\"|grep -i \"faea4372d3a65bdbd7969752f0d5948ca21c5571\"|grep -v grep|awk '{print \"kill -9 \" \$1}'|sh"' errored out: Error: spawn bash ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[XCUITest] Real device logger '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deviceconsole' is a directory. Appending 'deviceconsole' executable
[debug] [XCUITest] Using real device logger '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deviceconsole/deviceconsole'
[debug] [XCUITest] Using Xcode configuration file: '/src/main/resources/myconfig.xcconfig'
[debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild build test -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=faea4372d3a65bdbd7969752f0d5948ca21c5571 -configuration Debug -xcconfig /src/main/resources/myconfig.xcconfig' in directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Waiting for WebDriverAgent to start on device
[debug] [XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /Users/arun.sambu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/F08249A4-D6EB-4D3A-9354-0E638607CC28/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-02-03_142740-DZsDR7.log
[Xcode] 2017-02-03 14:27:41.093 xcodebuild[4292:81409] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/arun.sambu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/F08249A4-D6EB-4D3A-9354-0E638607CC28/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-02-03_142740-DZsDR7.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/arun.sambu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/F08249A4-D6EB-4D3A-9354-0E638607CC28/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-02-03_142740-DZsDR7.log}

[Xcode] 
Testing failed:
    ./Scripts/generate_modules.sh: line 15: Modules/module.modulemap: No such file or directory
** TEST FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Generate\ modules /Users/arun.sambu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Intermediates/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentLib.build/Script-AD35D0281CF1B37A00870A75.sh

[Xcode] (1 failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your current user has write permissions to the folder where Appium is currently installed.

You can find some help here to change permission: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16180/xcode-problem-with-directory-permissions

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved with Appium 1.6.3.

if you still face any issues, you can find the solution here:
https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md

Answer (score 0):

Code 65 is the issue with code_signing,
If xcode config is not working for you, try manually signing WebDriverAgent in Xcode, that should do the trick, however I would suggest upgrading to 1.6.4, in which this issue has been resolved:

Allow for the auto-generation of the Xcode config file used to configurable
WDA before launch. This includes two new desired capabilities
xcodeOrgId - the Apple developer team identifier string
xcodeSigningId - a string representing a signing certificate, defaulting to
"iPhone Developer"

Below is the link:
https://github.com/appium/appium/releases